# React: Cloning and assigning prop to nested children

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I want to make `<Form>` component like in `HTML` form. I want to check if all the children inside the form component is valid. If all valid, then submit the form.

This is my code which assigns `setValid()` property. When the children is valid, it will call this `setValid()` method from the property.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (children) {
      const reccurse = (children: ReactNode, prefix: string) => {
        let clones = [] as ReactNode[];
        Children.forEach(children, (child, index) => {
          let c = child as React.ReactElement;
          if (c) {
            let extraProps = { key: prefix + '-' + index } as { [key: string]: any };

            //If child has property `required` then it needs to be validated
            if (c.props && c.props['required']) {

              //set initial valid status as false
              dispatch({ key: prefix + '-' + index, value: false });

              //set property `setValid` function to be called if the field is valid
              extraProps['setValid'] = (valid: boolean) => {
                dispatch({ key: prefix + '-' + index, value: valid });
              };
            }

            //if the component has children, reccurse the children
            if (c.props && c.props.children) {
              extraProps['children'] = reccurse(c.props.children, prefix + '-' + index);
            }

            //assign the clone with added property
            clones.push(React.cloneElement(c, { ...extraProps, ...c.props }));
          }
        })
        return clones;
      }

      setClonedChildren(reccurse(children, ''));
    }
  }, [])

....

return <DefaultView style={[styles.form, style]} {...otherProps}>{clonedChildren}{submitBtn}</DefaultView>;
```

I have this super weird problem. If the `Input` is the direct children of the `Form` component, then it works fine. For example:

```
<Form>
  <Input required={true} />
</Form>
```

this works fine.

But if the `Input` is at `level 2 and above`, somehow the `setValid()` property is gone after `return clones` being called. For example:

```
<Form>
  <View>
    <Input required={true} />
  </View>

  -- OR --

  <View>
    <View>
      <Input required={true} />
    </View>
  </View>

</Form>
```

I tried to switch the `{...extraProps, ...c.props}` into `{...c.props, ...extraProps}`. After the code returns from `return clones`, `setValid` property is still there, this is shown in the debugger, but there are multiple errors occurs when rendering.

> react-dom.development.js:25058 Uncaught Error: Element type is
> invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a
> class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
> likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
> or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> The above error occurred in the  component:
>
> Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error
> handling behavior. Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to
> learn more about error boundaries.
>
> react-native-logs.fx.ts:22 Cannot record touch end without a touch
> start.  Touch End:
> {"identifier":0,"pageX":484,"pageY":21,"timestamp":4173.9000000003725}
> Touch Bank: [] warn @ react-native-logs.fx.ts:22
>
> react-dom.development.js:25058 Uncaught Error: Element type is
> invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a
> class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
> likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
> or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

I am confused why it is working when the `Input` is the direct child of the `Form`, but does not work on `level 2 and above`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my updated code:

```
useEffect(() => {
if (children) {
  const reccurse = (cldrn: ReactNode, prefix: string) => {
    let clones = [] as ReactNode[];
    Children.forEach(cldrn, (child, index) => {
      let c = child as React.ReactElement;
      let { children, ...props } = c.props ?? {};

      if (c) {
        if (typeof (c) === 'string') {
          clones.push(c);
        } else {
          let extraProps = { key: prefix + '-' + index } as { [key: string]: any };
          if (props && props['required']) {
            dispatch({ key: prefix + '-' + index, value: false });
            extraProps['setValid'] = (valid: boolean) => {
              dispatch({ key: prefix + '-' + index, value: valid });
            };
          }
          if (children) {
            extraProps['children'] = reccurse([...children], prefix + '-' + index);
          }
          clones.push(React.cloneElement(c, { ...extraProps, ...props }));
        }
      }
    })
    return clones;
  }

  setClonedChildren(reccurse(children, ''));
}
}, [])
```

The problem is this code:

```
clones.push(React.cloneElement(c, { ...extraProps, ...c.props }));
```

when `...extraProps` contains `children` and `...c.props` also contains `children`, it is getting overlapped by the original children which is `...c.props`. So I have to separate them by:

```
let { children, ...props } = c.props ?? {};
```

and make sure I do not overlap it when cloning the child. It works fine now. Also there is another checker, which check if the child is a string, then the code just push it into the children array without cloning it.

```
if (typeof (c) === 'string') {
  clones.push(c); //no need React.cloneElement()
}
```